# Clarifying Proof that Span(v$_1, $v$_2,...,$v$_n$) is a Subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Theorem:** If **v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$ are elements of a vector space $V$ then Span(**v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$) is a
>   subspace of $V$.

I understand the proof of the closure properties under addition and scalar multiplication, but what I am confused about is why Span(**v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$) is a subset to begin with.

A subset will contain elements of $V$ and the theorem states that **v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$ are elements of a vector space $V$. So then why is Span(**v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$) a subset when it doesn't contain elements of $V$, since it is the set of all linear combinations of **v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First keep in mind (as you have said) that $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are in $V$.

Since $V$ is a vector space it is closed under scalar multiplication, so all possible elements $\alpha_1v_1,\alpha_2v_2,\ldots,\alpha_nv_n$ are in $V$.

Since $V$ is a vector space it is also closed under addition.  So all possible elements $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n$ (that is, linear combinations) are in $V$.

But such expressions are exactly the elements of ${\rm span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$.  So all elements of ${\rm span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ are in $V$.

Answer (score 4):

$V$, being a vector space, is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. Thus any linear combination of elements of $\{v_1, ... , v_n\}$ is in $V$, so Span($\{v_1, ... , v_n\}$) is a subset of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confusing the language "**v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$ are elements of a vector space $V$" with the language "**v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$ are *all of the* elements of a vector space $V$".  The two statements are different.  The former only means that **v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$ are *among the* elements of a vector space $V$, but there could be others (and there are -- the linear combinations of **v**$_1, $**v**$_2,...,$**v**$_n$, and even more if these vectors don't span $V$).